# \documentclass{asl} Command \negmedspace already defined error

Tags: amsmath

Others have had a similar problem.  I use

```
\RequirePackage[2020/10/01]{latexrelease}

\AddToHook{package/before/amsmath}{%
  \let\negmedspace\relax
  \let\negthickspace\relax
}

\documentclass[asl]{asl}

\usepackage{ibycus4}
\usepackage{amsfonts, eucal, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\title[a group-theoretic account of art history]{A Group-Theoretic Account of Art History %As a Family of Formal Theories
}

\maketitle

This is a test.
$2 + 2 = 4$.

\end{document}
```

However, the error `Command \negmedspace already defined' persists.  Thanks in advance for consideration of this problem, which somehow arose for me only quite recently in the case of a file that has compiled without problems for many months.

Comment: I don't have your class, but it shouldn't be necessary to set `\negmedspace` before amsmath in a current tex system. Probably someelse defines it.

Comment: we can't debug code we can't see can you provide links to the packge also to "Others have had a similar problem" you don't say what others  or what the problem is. What is defining negmedspace, and why?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I simply commented out the definitions, by means of \newcommand, of \negmedspace and \thickmedspace within asl.cls, which is an assemblage, due to Y. Moschavakis, of pieces from amsart.cls and other packages from AMS Latex that was sponsored by the Association for Symbolic Logic and has not changed in over twenty years.  Why this problem arose suddenly is unclear to me.  In any case, everything is now all right.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it seems that it appeared with texlive 2021. On overleaf you can manually choose your texlive version, and with texlive 2020 the problem doesn't appear.